# What is the opposite of genderless - genderful?

Tags: word-request, antonyms

There is the word "genderless" (http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/genderless), however there is no such word as "genderful", so what word should I use instead?

Comment: Also see *[sexed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sexed)*,  “having a sex; being male or female”

Comment: @jwpat7: Also *"having been **assigned** a sex"* - which in the case of [two-day-old male chicks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chick_culling) is an assignment I'm sure they'd rather forego!

Comment: I would just say "gendered"; "gendered" is to have gender, "genderless" is to be without it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on the exact context, but often just **gender** would work...

> 1: If one wished to apply adelphoi specifically to one gender or the other, one had to couple it with a [gender](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8QMmY59kJkEC&pg=PA83&dq=%22%20a%20gender%20noun%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zte9UavaDcLy0gXp54HYCg&ved=0CFUQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22%20a%20gender%20noun%22&f=false) noun.

In other contexts (or simply through stylistic preference) you could use **gendered**...

> 2: The relationship between a [gendered](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rkZkDz0Hg_sC&pg=PA29&dq=%22%20a%20gendered%20division%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Zti9UYiIFKiu0QXzyYGADw&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22%20a%20gendered%20division%22&f=false) division of work and a gendered division of dominance was a crucial issue.

But probably the most "general-purpose" form is **gender-based**...

> 3: Similarly, a [gender-based](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=uKKfaQUL3HsC&pg=PA64&dq=%22%20a%20gender%20based%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=F9m9Ud6vGMfP0QWg0YHoCg&ved=0CEAQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=%22%20a%20gender%20based%22&f=false) analysis that considers sexual orientation would be essential to understanding the often troubled political and social relationships between lesbians and gay men.

A few people have used [genderised](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22%20a%20gender%20noun%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22%20a%20genderised%22&oq=%22%20a%20genderised%22&gs_l=serp.3...4323.6390.0.6765.10.10.0.0.0.1.312.1010.7j2j0j1.10.0...0.0...1c.1.17.psy-ab.sabeual5hV4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=dc3bdb21c054a890&biw=1296&bih=930), but I wouldn't recommend that one at the moment. Though I can imagine it becoming more useful in future, if and when biotechnology advances to the point where we routinely force a "non-sex-differentiated cell" to definitely become one sex or the other.

Comment: Good answer!  *Genderised* is interesting.  I haven't heard it before, and I don't much like the sound of it--too much like *tenderised*, I think.